# create N lists of maximum lengt K with all possible orderings

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

Given a list of length N in Python:

```
a = [A,B,C]
```

I want to create all possible combinations of lists with a set maximum length (in this case 2). The order of the elements also matters. This is what I would like as result:

```
[A,B],[C]
[B,A],[C]

[A,C],[B]
[C,A],[B]

[B,C],[A]
[C,B],[A]
```

I think the [permutations function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is a good place to start. But I can't figure out how to get the exact results.

Comment: you don't want `[A], [B], [C]` ? The maximum length has to be attained ?

Comment: @Jacquot, yes. In a practical sense I'm trying to plan how many people will fit in the least amount of cars. Although the problem is more complex than that. So I want to fill up all cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for v in permutations(a):
    for i in range(0, len(v), 2):
        print v[i:i+2]
    print '-'*10
```

Output:

```
('A', 'B')
('C',)
----------
('A', 'C')
('B',)
----------
('B', 'A')
('C',)
----------
('B', 'C')
('A',)
----------
('C', 'A')
('B',)
----------
('C', 'B')
('A',)
----------
```